# Rails 5 - Heroku: Precompiling assets failed (Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...lflings-regular": expected ")

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, rubygems

I'm trying to push tutorial blog rails (5.2.1) app to heroku. I've checked all similar questions on SO and haven't found the answer. The errors I'm getting are:

```
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        I, [2020-02-21T17:17:19.342502 #751]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_9a4b8f93edcb6949bd3f6eab0443fee7/public/assets/blog-c4dff50241ee865870a1e61848b014b1bfe41645844507124353abe96a2d563a.jpg
remote:        I, [2020-02-21T17:17:19.348422 #751]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_9a4b8f93edcb6949bd3f6eab0443fee7/public/assets/workplace-8b957cb3928834865a124fc613d371b51b2bd32f806caa4fef1d538ea6af0bcf.jpg
remote:        I, [2020-02-21T17:17:24.225768 #751]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_9a4b8f93edcb6949bd3f6eab0443fee7/public/assets/application-b0891f71e83fe8da7539d2c04309266db2d56be33bf3a5453b8ada6570a61a16.js
remote:        I, [2020-02-21T17:17:24.226500 #751]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_9a4b8f93edcb6949bd3f6eab0443fee7/public/assets/application-b0891f71e83fe8da7539d2c04309266db2d56be33bf3a5453b8ada6570a61a16.js.gz
remote:        DEPRECATION WARNING on line 12 of /tmp/build_9a4b8f93edcb6949bd3f6eab0443fee7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.4.1/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-mincer.scss:
remote:        #{} interpolation near operators will be simplified in a future version of Sass.
remote:        To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:
remote:        
remote:          unquote("\"<%- asset_path(\"#{$path}\".replace(/[#?].*$/, '')) + \"#{$path}\".replace(/(^[^#?]*)([#?]?.*$)/, '$2') %>\"")
remote:        
remote:        You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        DEPRECATION WARNING on line 16 of /tmp/build_9a4b8f93edcb6949bd3f6eab0443fee7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.4.1/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-mincer.scss:
remote:        #{} interpolation near operators will be simplified in a future version of Sass.
remote:        To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:
remote:        
remote:          unquote('"<%- asset_path("#{$file}") %>"')
remote:        
remote:        You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...lflings-regular": expected ")", was ".eot".replace(/..."
remote:        (sass):314
remote:        /tmp/build_9a4b8f93edcb6949bd3f6eab0443fee7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.7.4/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1308:in `expected'
```

and:

```
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to alpha-blog-emir.
```

My custom.css.scss file is:

```
$navbar-default-bg: #010101;

@import "bootstrap-mincer";
@import "bootstrap"; 

#logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#logo:hover{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.center{
  text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image: asset-url('workplace.jpg');
  height: 600px;
}

.jumbotron h1{
  color: #010101;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn-xlarge {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  background-color: black;
}

.article-actions{
  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.description{
  margin-top: 0;
}

.article-title{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.article-body{
  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

footer{
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  color: #777;
}

footer a:hover{
  color: #222;
}

footer small{
  float: left;
}

footer ul{
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

footer ul li{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

I have tryied with rails assets:precompile command but that didn't help. I've also checked for errors in custom.css.scss file but I couldn't find any. I understand that there is some sass syntax error on line: 314, but how can I find that error?

Comment: That file doesn't look like the problem, do you have any font stylesheets or other scss in your project?

Comment: I have only application.css file with 2 lines: 
 `*= require_tree .
 *= require_self`

Comment: Try changing your file to `custom.scss` instead of `custom.css.scss`

Comment: Tried that, didn't help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it after you drove my attention to bootstrap-mincer. I've changed 
@import "bootstrap-mincer"; to 
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"; line in my custom.css.scss file and now everything works. Thx...

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation from [bootstrap-mincer](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-mincer.scss):

```
// Mincer asset helper functions
//
// This must be imported into a .css.ejs.scss file.
// Then, <% %>-interpolations will be parsed as strings by Sass, and evaluated by EJS after Sass compilation.
```

Assuming you already have EJS hooked into your asset pipeline, your file needs to be named `custom.css.ejs.scss`.